# Can Entity Framework 6 be used in a .NET Standard project?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-standard

And if not, will it be? If so, when?

I haven't been able to find any clear official information on this, and the limited information I was able to find on Stack Overflow is a year or two old.

I was able to find official information saying EF 6.3 will be able to be used in a .NET Core project, but I couldn't find a release date for it, nor am I sure what the implications for use in a .NET Standard project are.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EF 6 supports .NET Standard 2.1, which is currently supported by .NET Core 3.0 or later - no .NET Framework version. EF 6 also supports .NET 4.0 and 4.5 or later.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/release/6.4/src/EntityFramework/EntityFramework.csproj#L6

Comment: Does Entity Framework 6 (latest version 6.4.4) support .NET Standard 2.0?

Comment: @petrosmm No it doesn't. That says .NET Standard 2.1.  EF6 doesn't support .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Wow, I was under the impression per Fuget that it supported 2.0 but per @Ogglas below, you're correct.

Answer (score 12):

Some clarification, since `EntityFramework 6.3.0` `.NET Standard 2.1` has been supported. However there is no `.NET Framework` version that supports `.NET Standard 2.1`. Comment from Microsoft:

> NET Framework won't support .NET Standard 2.1 or later versions. For
>   more details, see the announcement of [.NET Standard 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/).

This means that a majority of all applications using `EntityFramework 6.X` won't be able to use the `.NET Standard 2.1` project anyway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/#

Comment: Recommendation is to build your library using ef 6 to target .net 4 and .net standard so it can support running on .net 4 and .net core

Comment: @TWilly can you please expand?

Comment: Well, this is very misleading to users in .NET Framework that see "EF6 now supports .NET Core in 6.3'. Sure, it supports .NET core, but by tossing .NET Framework that sort of defeats the point (yes, I understand it's still useful to .NET core, but it should be made quite clear that it doesn't support .NET framework)