# is it possible to register a .NET framework DbContext inside a .NET core web app startup?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

when I want to register my DBContext (which is defined in a separate .NET 4.6.1 framework class library) in a .NET Core web project startUp.cs, I get this error:*"the type context cannot be used as type parameter TContext in the generic type or method..."*

***startUp.cs:***

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationContext"));
                    
                }
            );
```

I cannot create a new .NET Core class library because I have a few other legacy ASP.Net MVC 5 web apps that use this old class library.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you several DB contexts for net 4. You still can create Net 5 one. Since Net 5 is async it is better to use it for net core. Or you can try standard, but there is no much sense  to do it.

Comment: If you're going to have a class library be consumed by .NET Framework and .NET Core apps, you should target [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard). Also, Entity Framework Core targets .NET Standard, so you can make use of that in both your .NET Framework and .NET Core apps instead of using the old (non Core) Entity Framework.

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't use .NET Framework library in .NET Core application.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58381122/861716. But still, this service registration can't be used for non-core EF contexts.

Comment: @GertArnold I see...,then I have to create a new .NET Core class library for my .NET Core Web Application...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my .NET 5 project working with EF6 with this sample codes provided by Microsoft.. now it's fully working!

here is the sample project:

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/data/entity-framework-6/3.xsample

Comment: Do you understand why it's working though? It uses the .NET Standard 2.1 version of EF 6.4.

Comment: didn't matter what .NET standard version I was using, the solution was editing the context file . I added a new constructor in order to pass the 'Connection String'

Comment: Not only does it matter, it's the only thing that matters. You can't use .NET Framework libraries in .NET Core. Period. The only reason you're able to use EF 6.4 is that unlike older EF 6 versions, EF 6.4 also targets .NET Standard. By upgrading your .NET Old code to use EF 6.4, you used the only version that can be used in both runtimes.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much you edit your context file if you keep targeting an EF 6 version that can't run on .NET Core.